# Read artificial intelligence training data (.csv) to specific data structure in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, data-structures, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to python and I'm trying to perform a simple task which is to read a .csv file and save it in a specific data structure. I'm using numpy to load the data and I get a `ndarray` of `ndarray`'s, which is not exactly what I want.

My code:

```
import numpy
filename = '../HTRU2/HTRU_2.csv'
raw_data = open(filename, 'rU')
data = numpy.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=',')
```

The data structure I'm looking for is a `list` of `tuples`. The `tuples` are a pair (x,y) of `ndarray`s: *x* is a `ndarray` of shape (*nx* - 1, 1) filled with `float`s, where *nx* is the number of elements of each line in the file minus 1; y is a `ndarray` of shape (1, 1) that holds the last element of the line (also a `float`).

You might think this is some crazy data structure I've made up, but it's actually quite useful since my end goal is to put this in a Neural Network (if you know about NN's you probably guessed the tuple is actually a pair of inputs/output, where both are a column matrix). I must not change the data structure.

File sample:

```
140.5625,55.68378214,-0.234571412,-0.699648398,3.199832776,19.11042633,7.975531794,74.24222492,0
102.5078125,58.88243001,0.465318154,-0.515087909,1.677257525,14.86014572,10.57648674,127.3935796,0
```

Each tuple would look like this:

```
#     x                      y
[[140.5625]               
[55.68378214]
[-0.234571412]
[-0.699648398]
[3.199832776]
[19.11042633]
[7.975531794]
[74.24222492]]     ,      [[0]]
```

Comment: Some sample input & resulting data structure would be very helpful. Also I would guess you probably don't want this structure, but to simply index your ndarray properly, or throw it in a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @miradulo I knew I was missing something, sorry. Will edit in a few seconds.

Comment: First, can you get a reasonable 2d array of floats from the `csv`?  No errors, complaints about unequal number columns, `nan` for strings, etc?  If that's the case, then lets not worry about the `csv` anymore, and focus on converting an array into your structure.

Comment: @hpaulj I get no errors, just a perfect 2d array which doesn't do much for me.

Comment: Why do you need each of the floats to be in its own `ndarray`?  It doesn't make much sense.  `data.tolist()` will convert that array into a list of lists.  You could then iterate through the list and turn the sublists into tuples.

Comment: Use pytorch instead of numpy for nn training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution:

```
import numpy
filename = '../HTRU2/test.csv'
file = open(filename, 'rU')
data = numpy.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',')
training_data = list()
for test in data:
    training_data.append((test[:-1].reshape(8, 1), test[-1].reshape(1, 1)))
```

Where the number of input neurons is 8 and the number of output neurons is 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [60]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [61]: data
Out[61]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [62]: data.tolist()
Out[62]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
In [63]: [tuple(l) for l in _]
Out[63]: [(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11)]
In [64]: [tuple(np.array(i) for i in l) for l in __]
Out[64]: 
[(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3)),
 (array(4), array(5), array(6), array(7)),
 (array(8), array(9), array(10), array(11))]
In [65]: [tuple(np.array(i) for i in l) for l in data]
Out[65]: 
[(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3)),
 (array(4), array(5), array(6), array(7)),
 (array(8), array(9), array(10), array(11))]
```

---

But do you really need a tuple layer?  Why not just add a dimension:

```
In [67]: data.reshape(3,4,1)
Out[67]: 
array([[[ 0],
        [ 1],
        [ 2],
        [ 3]],

       [[ 4],
        [ 5],
        [ 6],
        [ 7]],

       [[ 8],
        [ 9],
        [10],
        [11]]])
```

Comment: It's close to what I need but the tuples are not exactly what I specified. My tuples need be something like a pair (x,y), which I can then do `for x,y in tuple`. Please see the example I wrote in the question.

Comment: OK, so you have an extra layer of `ndarray` nesting.  It's a pain to separate out the layers of tuple and ndarray in your display.  It's not really clear whether your content of the tuples is a 2d array or 1d array with object dtype.

Comment: It does resemble what I asked, but I need it to be tuple based. I've reformulated my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
filename = '../HTRU2/HTRU_2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

The second argument may be unnecessary

Finally:

```
df = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
```

Comment: That simply gives me a pandas.DataFrame which is essentially an array of arrays (or something like it)

Comment: sorry I missed that part of your question initially. try my edit. Also, it's more like an array of a Pandas Series data structure...really nice syntax comparable to R's dplyr

Comment: I think it's still not creating the tuple I need. I've edited my question to include both a sample of the file and the resulting data structure.

Comment: I actually use this exact approach in my own code, so it should work. can you specify what's wrong with the output this gives you?

Comment: If after your code I run the code I actually need to run it gives me an error. 
Code: 
`for _tupple in df:
    for x,y in _tupple:
        doSomething(x,y)`
Error: "numpy.float64" object is not iterable.

Comment: I would recommend that you post another question with the details of that function.. creating a list of tuples from a CSV is pretty straightforward

Comment: It never executes that function, it crashes with the error I said on `for x,y in _tupple:`. I know that because the function I'm testing with is literally just a `print("Hi!")`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165993/discussion-between-mike-palmice-and-daniel-marques).